# How can I filter the Highlighted content web part to only show things that the user flagged as "Save for later"?

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter

Seems like it should be pretty straight forward however I am not seeing it.

There is already a baked in feature where people can tag a page or document "Save for later" at the bottom of most pages above the comments section.

Highlighted content web part is also built in, however I can't seem to marry the two easily. The only custom filtering I see is "managed properties" but I am not sure if I can harness that for filtering a Highlighted content web part to only show things the user has "Saved for later".

Answer (score 0):

One thing I just noticed in our tenant recently is a new "Saved for later" webpart.  It isn't very flexible but it does give the basically functionality needed by showing the users a list of their "Saved for later" pages.